# How to compile and run pjsua2 demo app in qt creator?

Tags: c++, qt-creator, voip, pjsip, pjsua2

I am trying to build voip app in Qt creator. I don't have much expirience at C++. I installed Qt and built and installed pjproject library. I added pjproject library with pkgconfig like this [Adding library to qt project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MvyD.jpg)

> Here is source code [code on GitHub](https://github.com/svaba1012/VoIp-Qt-Project),

Here is my .pro file:

```
QT += quick

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

resources.files = main.qml 
resources.prefix = /$${TARGET}
RESOURCES += resources

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

unix: CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
unix: PKGCONFIG += libpjproject

unix: PKGCONFIG += openssl
```

Inside pjproject directory I found **./pjsip-apps/src/samples/pjsua2_demo.cpp** file with perfect skeleton code for my project, so I copied code from that file to my main file of the project.

**This is error that I get:**

[Image of errors in Qt Creator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxYKb.png)

Here are some lines of errors:

1. gsm.c:-1: error: undefined reference to `gsm_decode' :-1: error: /usr/local/lib/libpjmedia-codec-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a(gsm.o): in function` gsm_codec_encode':
2. :-1: error: /usr/local/lib/libpjmedia-codec-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a(speex_codec.o): in function `spx_codec_decode': speex_codec.c:-1: error: undefined reference to` speex_bits_read_from'
3. :-1: error: /usr/local/lib/libpjmedia-audiodev-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a(alsa_dev.o): in function `alsa_factory_refresh': alsa_dev.c:-1: error: undefined reference to` snd_device_name_hint'
4. ...

I tried running compiled version of **pjsua2_demo.cpp** and everything worked fine.
Executable location **./pjsip-apps/bin/samples/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu** inside pjproject directory. I suspect that the problem is in including library and linking it to the project, but I am not sure how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you use "*,pro" rather than `cmake` for your project? What do you need `QT += quick` for? The error says you need to link your app against some library. What does the library documentation say about using it?

Comment: Thanks @zkoza. I am using `QT += quick` , because I am planing to use `QML` for `UI` later in the project. There are `cmake` and `qmake` what makes it different? I linked app against `pjproject` library and linker is complaining about some parts of library and I am not sure why, other parts are totally okay (I get higher number of error when not importing pjproject app).

Comment: Did you follow Chapter 8 of https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject/blob/master/README.txt ?

Comment: Thanks @zkoza , I tried, maybe I should switch to `cmake`  instead of `qmake` , but with `cmake` I don't know how to link *pjproject* with my app. Can you help?

Comment: Perhaps I can help. I need a full source code (preferably  [mre] or GitHub link, etc.) including the complete `*.pro` file used to compile the program. So that everything is reproducible.

Comment: Here is source code [code on GitHub](https://github.com/svaba1012/VoIp-Qt-Project), take a look @zkoza

Comment: After I installed `pjproject` library, I managed to compile & run your program in a console: `qmake pjsipSmor.pro` to generate `Makefile`,  then `make` to compile,  `./pjsipSmor` to run. I guess you have some old libraries installed or you miss some libraries.

Comment: I guees that I have made some mistake during installation of `pjproject` library. Can you explain me how have you installed it @zkoza ? Are you compiling on linux os or windows os?

Comment: @zkoza are you using qt5 or qt6? I don't have qmake program installed.

Comment: Manjaro Linux, all installations via a package manager. Every working installation of Qt must have `qmake`.  Mine is at `/usr/bin/qmake`. `qmake -v` returns 
`QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.15.8 in /usr/lib`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't managed to find solution for *.pro* build file, so I decided to try with *cmake*. I found solution on [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76435330/cmake-project-with-pjsip-library) and combined it with comment of [tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev) user.

Here is my *cmake* file from my [project](https://github.com/svaba1012/BjSip):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(bjSip VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

#adding pthread flags for pjsip
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.4 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Quick LinguistTools )
#qt_create_translation(QM_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} translationSR.ts)
#configure_file(${QM_FILES} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} COPYONLY)

#add pkgconfig tool for linking pjsip lib
INCLUDE(FindPkgConfig)
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)

pkg_check_modules(PJSIP "libpjproject")

add_definitions(${PJSIP_CFLAGS})
#adding paths to include dirs and static library
include_directories(${PJSIP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(/cpp/include)
link_directories(${PJSIP_STATIC_LIBRARY_DIRS})

qt_standard_project_setup()

qt_add_executable(appbjSip
    main.cpp
    cpp/sip/bjendpoint.h cpp/sip/bjendpoint.cpp
    cpp/sip/bjcall.h cpp/sip/bjcall.cpp
    cpp/sip/bjaudiomediaport.h cpp/sip/bjaudiomediaport.cpp
    cpp/sip/bjaccount.h cpp/sip/bjaccount.cpp
    cpp/sip/bjsip.h cpp/sip/bjsip.cpp

    Models/local-storage.js
    Models/user-model.js
    Models/contact-model.js
    Models/call-history-model.js
    Utils/changeBrightness.js
    Utils/getBuddiesUsernames.js
    Resources.qrc
    ${QM_FILES}
)


qt_add_qml_module(appbjSip
    URI bjSip
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES   Main.qml
                ./Views/MenuView.qml
                ./Views/AndroidView.qml
                ./Views/DesktopView.qml
                ./Views/LoginView.qml
                ./Views/RegisterView.qml
                ./Views/CallView.qml
                ./Views/SettingView.qml
                ./Views/AppBar.qml
                ./Components/Forms/LoginForm.qml
                ./Components/Forms/RegisterForm.qml
                ./Components/Forms/AddNewContactForm.qml
                ./Components/Reusables/FontAwesomeIcons.qml
                ./Components/Reusables/ColorTheme.qml
                ./Components/Reusables/Icon.qml
                ./Components/Reusables/CustomTextField.qml
                ./Components/Reusables/CustomSpinBox.qml
                ./Components/Reusables/CustomButton.qml
                ./Components/Reusables/CustomLink.qml
                ./Components/Reusables/CustomText.qml
                ./Components/Reusables/CustomTabView.qml
                ./Components/Reusables/CustomTabButton.qml
                ./Components/Reusables/CustomComboBox.qml
                ./Components/Reusables/AvatarGroup.qml
                ./Components/Reusables/RoundedButton.qml
                ./Components/Reusables/Circle.qml
                ./Components/Reusables/Avatar.qml
                ./Components/Reusables/QuaterCircle.qml
                ./Components/Reusables/AppLogo.qml
                ./Components/Reusables/AppLogoWithText.qml
                ./Components/Users/ContactList.qml
                ./Components/Users/ContactListItem.qml
                ./Components/Users/AddNewContact.qml
                ./Components/Calls/VoiceCallUserBox.qml
                ./Components/Calls/CallAnswerButton/CallAnswerButton.qml
                ./Components/Calls/CallAnswerButton/CallAnswerButtonAnimatedBorder.qml
                ./Components/Calls/CallPendingScreen.qml
                ./Components/Calls/CallPendingDots/CallPendingDot.qml
                ./Components/Calls/CallPendingDots/CallPendingDots.qml
                ./Components/Calls/CallFooter.qml
                ./Components/Calls/CallGrid.qml
                ./Components/Calls/CallHistory.qml
                ./Components/Calls/CallHistoryItem.qml
                ./Components/Calls/CallEnded.qml
                ./Components/Calls/IncomingCallPopup/IncomingCallPopup.qml
                ./Models/AppState.qml
                Resources.qrc
)

set_target_properties(appbjSip PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

#linking with pjsip lib and other dependent libs
target_link_libraries(appbjSip PRIVATE ${PJSIP_STATIC_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(appbjSip PRIVATE Threads::Threads)
target_link_libraries(appbjSip PRIVATE OpenSSL::Crypto)
target_link_libraries(appbjSip PRIVATE OpenSSL::SSL)

target_link_libraries(appbjSip
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick
)

install(TARGETS appbjSip
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)
```

For other people with similar problem adapt *cmake* file for your needs, keeping lines with *PJSIP* variables.